# Bearer token doesn't get updated in request (Chrome)

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, authorization, jwt, bearer-token

I'm using AngularJS (1.6.1) and created an AuthorizationInterceptor.

When I add the access_token from local_storage to the 'Authorization' header it doesn't get updated in Chrome. It seems Chrome 'cached' the request

The token changes in local-storage but when Chrome does the actual request it always uses the same token (checked with Dev Tools, Postman and Fiddler...)

```
this.request = function (request) {
   request.headers = request.headers || {};
   if (window.localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== '') {
        alert("Adding header in request \n \n" + window.localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
        request.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
   }
   return request;
};
```

I tried the following:

```
this.request = function (request) {
   request.headers = request.headers || {};
   if (window.localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== '') {
        //alert("Adding header in request \n \n" + window.localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
        request.headers.TEST= 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
   }
   return request;
};
```

Now I'm not setting the Authorization header anymore but a 'TEST' header.

[image]

The test header now has the correct 'access_token' but there is still an 'Authorization' header? I don't know where it's coming from. It's nowhere programmed to add the header.

I also don't know where Chrome gets this access token from. It's one of yesterday. It's not in the request object either...
Also after deleting every saved information of the domain using Chrome settings, Chrome still manages to use an old token.

[image]

If I reinstall Chrome the bug is solved. Until it happens again...
The bug is not present in Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer

Did someone had a similar bug?
I'm getting desperate

Sincerly,
Brecht

Comment: i have same problem on angular and chrome :(

Comment: It's 2023 and I'm still facing this issue with Chrome 115 and my React App. I already had this issue in two totally different React projects.
Does anybody know if there is some bug report filed yet? 
Unfortunatelly the behaviour not clearly reproducable for me, just happened sporadically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I solved it by using a factory instead of a service for my interceptor.

**EDIT: The issue was gone for 5 months, after 5 months suddenly it stopped working again. Same behavior: Correct access_token in local storage, and correct token added in request (js code), but wrong token is sent in the actual XHR call. After reinstalling Chrome problem was solved again...**